# Per-user cumulative CPU time across reboots

Tags: shell, command-line, cpu-usage

I have installed the process accounting package ([`acct`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/acct)) and recorded data.

Using [`sa --print-seconds --user-summary | grep "$USER"`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sa), I get the process account summary for my user:

```
wjwrpoyob                            3548   19673.67re      11.07cp         0avio   3989884k
```

If I run it again after a second, the total CPU time for the user decreases (from 19673.67 real CPU seconds to 19634.93 real CPU seconds), which shouldn't be possible:

```
wjwrpoyob                            3555   19634.93re      11.05cp         0avio   3982032k
```

**How can I obtain the total CPU time by a single user (myself) and a combined total of all users using `sa`?**

`sleep 3` should count nearly 0 seconds towards CPU time (since it's not using the CPU), and `timeout 3s openssl speed` (CPU-intesive process running for 3 seconds) should count nearly 3 seconds towards CPU time.

---

```
> sa --print-seconds --user-summary --merge
sa: can't specify `--user-summary' or `--group-summary' with `--merge'

> sa --print-seconds --merge
couldn't open file '/var/log/account/savacct~': Permission denied

> ls /var/log/account/savacct~ /var/log/account/savacct
ls: cannot access '/var/log/account/savacct~': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '/var/log/account/savacct': No such file or directory
```

Comment: could you please retry your experiment adding --merge to sa's list of options ?

Comment: @MC68020 I have added the outputs of your suggestion to this post.